# How to close all child windows with a method

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

Having hard time dealing with this because every time I navigate to another form my project lags or is unresponsive for a few seconds before it shows the content of the window.

How can I close all the child windows with a method?

I have tried `this.Close()` but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm brand new to WPF, too.  I've been in WinForms and programming with the API for years, but I've finally decided to crack open WPF for my next project, and I don't know the first thing about it, but let's just have a look and see if we can stumble upon the answer.  What exactly is the problem?  You can't close a form window or you are trying to navigate between two windows and it's slow to navigate?

Comment: Could you post some code or an explanation of how you set up the program? I've personally never seen any lag when I open new windows in my WPF programs. Do you have any heavy initialization when you create them?

Answer (score 1):

You may use Application Class as a place of storing a links to the child windows. It creates a singleton Current which is accesable from any place

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  private List<Window> childWindows = new List<Window>();
  public List<Window> ChildWindows{get{return childWindows;}}
}
```

To register new ChildWindow add this into Initialized event handler

```
    private void ChildWindow_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ((App)Aplication.Current).Windows.Add(this);
    }
```

on ChildWindow Closing you have to remove link from collection

```
    private void ChildWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ((App)Aplication.Current).Windows.Remove(this) // here 
    }
```

if needs you may replace List with Dictionary to have a possibility of searching by key